# Were there any cases when EU country officials accused European Commission of not being informed properly on some matters?

Tags: european-union

In the recent months Romanian authorities initiated a legislative process for significantly changing some juridical laws leading to protests and also important disapproval messages from [European Union](https://www.romania-insider.com/ec-debate-justice-laws/) and US ([US urges Romanian Parliament to reject proposals that may weaken rule of law](https://www.romania-insider.com/us-urges-romanian-parliament-reject-proposals-may-weaken-rule-law/)):

> European Commission President Jean-Claude Juncker and First
>   Vice-President Frans Timmermans issued a joint statement expressing
>   their concerns about the latest developments in Romania regarding the
>   independence of the country’s judicial system and its capacity to
>   fight corruption.

The heads of Parliament Chambers responded to this message arguing that [EC is misinformed on justice laws](https://www.romania-insider.com/ec-misinformed-justice-laws/):

> The presidents of the Romanian Parliament’s two chambers, who are also
>   the leaders of the ruling coalition, signed a letter to the European
>   Commission’s leaders expressing their concern that the European
>   Commission was misinformed about the changes to the justice laws
>   recently passed by the Parliament.

EC has [provided a reply for this message](https://www.romania-insider.com/ec-informed-situation-romania/):

> “We are very well informed about this process, about the stakes and
>   potential risks. We have been in contact with the Government,
>   Parliament, the judicial system and civil society in Romania, within
>   the Cooperation and Verification Mechanism,” the EC representatives
>   added.

Clearly, accusing someone of being misinformed is far from being a decent official message and I suspect there will be repercussions.

**Question:** Were there any cases when EU country officials accused European Commission of not being informed properly on some matters?

Comment: There have certainly been disagreements in the past, although I'm unsure if the "misinformed" accusation has ever been used before. This is opinion, but I think there was a subtle warning in the EC reply, not to Romania but to Dragnea specifically. [OLAF and DNA](https://ec.europa.eu/anti-fraud/media-corner/news/13-11-2017/head-romanian-ruling-party-indicted-fraud-following-olaf-investigation_en) seem to be taking the issue seriously. My guess is that the EU is fully backing DNA, and Dragnea is feeling the pressure (he's probably not very far from the end of the mandate).

Comment: This [EU Observer](https://euobserver.com/) article came out today: [Romania's judicial overhaul risks Schengen hopes, Juncker warns](https://euobserver.com/justice/140788).

Comment: For another perspective on a subject related to this question (or at least I think it is) check the [opinion article by Daniel Dragomir](https://euobserver.com/opinion/140824) in the [EU Observer](https://euobserver.com/). I don't know the guy or his background but he seems to point out several alleged abuses made by the DNA to achieve a high conviction rate. The DNA efficiency has been praised by the EU.